# Subbase of a topology space, finite intersections and the subbase $\subset \tau$

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading my lecture notes and find the following definition of a subbase as well as a fact stated after that, which I can't seem to prove.

The definition:

> A family of subsets of $X$, $\mathcal{P}$ is called a *subbase* of $(X, \tau)$ if the family $I(\mathcal{P})$ is a base of $(X, \tau)$ where $I(\mathcal{P})$ is the family of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{P}$.

This definition is a translation from a non-English language. I've read lots of definitions of subbase originally written in English and they have the same meaning of my definition.

The fact:

> $\mathcal{P} \subset \tau$

Now, there's no proof in my notes, which probably means that the fact follows trivially. However I cannot see it. If for each $A \in \mathcal{P}$, $A \in I(\mathcal{P})$, then the proof is trivial but this could certainly be the case only if *all finite intersections* means that those where $i=1$ in $U_{1} \cap U_{2} \cap ... \cap U_{k}$ are also included. Is this true? I'm not sure. Also, if is true, does that mean that each member of the subbase is necessarily also in $I(\mathcal{P})$? This isn't stated anywhere in my notes, so I really can't decide whether to believe it or not.

Comment: "All finite intersections" means $$\bigcap_{A\in \mathcal{F}} A$$ for all finite subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{P}$. In particular for all subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of cardinality $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I read about the vacuous truths after reading your comment and the $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$ of an empty 

family of subsets of a set, which are $\emptyset$ and $X$ respectively in the current context. Also when 

$\mathcal{F}$ is $\{A\}$ for each $A \in \mathcal{P}$, then $A \in I(\mathcal{P})$. So, $\mathcal{P} 

\subset I(\mathcal{P})$ and $X \in I(\mathcal{P})$. The first leads to the fact. I hope I'm on the right 

track.

Comment: Right. The singletons $\mathcal{F} = \{A\}$ give us $\mathcal{P}\subset I(\mathcal{P}) \subset\tau$, and $\mathcal{F} = \varnothing$ ensures that $I(\mathcal{P})$ is indeed a basis of $\tau$, as it makes sure we can write $X$ as a union of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why not write it out as an answer?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Because I was busy answering elsewhere. Now I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{P}$" means

$$\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{F}} A$$

for all finite subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{P}$. In particular, for $B\in\mathcal{P}$, the singleton $\{B\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{P}$ and we have

$$B = \bigcap_{A\in \{B\}} A \in I(\mathcal{P}),$$

which gives the inclusion $\mathcal{P} \subset I(\mathcal{P})\subset\tau$.

Beyond that, $\mathcal{F} = \varnothing$ is also a finite subset, and

$$X = \bigcap_{A\in\varnothing} A \in I(\mathcal{P}).$$

This ensures that without any further assumptions on $\mathcal{P}$, the family $I(\mathcal{P})$ is a basis of $\tau$. If the intersection over an empty subfamily of $\mathcal{P}$ were excluded, one would have to demand that

$$X = \bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{P}} A$$

for $I(\mathcal{P})$ to be a basis, since otherwise the open set $X$ could not be written as a union of elements of $I(\mathcal{P})$.